# Unraid share fails to mount on OpenWRT using mount.cifs?

Tags: linux, samba, mount, cifs, openwrt

So I have an Unraid machine with some shares on it and I would like to be able to mount this share on my OpenWRT router for backing up/transfering files onto the router (avoids having to plug-in/remove USB constantly as the share is also mounted on my desktop).

I followed the guide [here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/nas/cifs.client) and everything worked until the mount command:

`mount.cifs //tower/dev /mnt/dev -o user=kris,dom=tower,vers=1.0`

I added the option `vers=1.0` after encountering the error `No dialect specified on mount`.

When running the above mount command, `dmesg` gives the following error:

`Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`

I also tried following [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/backuppc/mailman/backuppc-users/thread/4BACA9E3.9070104@gmail.com/) thread with no success, however I can successfully connect to the share using: `smbclient //tower/dev -U kris -W tower`
and `smbclient -L tower -U kris -W tower` also successfully lists the tower's shares.

From the other guides I have seen people have extra error messages along side this, but my `dmesg` log only shows the above error line. Executing the command also prints this in the terminal:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Any suggestions? I have checked `/mnt/dev` exists and I can't seem to find anywhere OpenWRT side to see any more information on the error.

Thanks!

Comment: seems like you're using `mount.cifs` with SMB v1, while `smbclient` uses highest possible SMB version. Try running `smbclient` with `-m NT1`, and see if you can still connect.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Samba releases disabled SMB1. If your WRT installation can't use any higher version, then you'll need to enable it in your smb.conf file (then restart samba). Depending upon the Samba version, you may need to use various settings, starting with:

```
ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
```

You may also need

```
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
```

Then don't forget to `systemctl restart smb` or `systemctl restart samba`  (depending upon your distribution/ version / release).

Check the [samba Wiki for more details.](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_4.11_Features_added/changed#SMB1_is_disabled_by_default)